# How to quote a specification like HTML5 in BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies

I have W3C specifications in my bibliography, I dont know how to quote them correctly. Now I do it like this:

```
@techreport{DefHtml,
  author = {Ian Hickson},
  title = {HTML5 Specification},
  institution = {World Wide Web Consortium},
  number = {1.5610},
  year = {2012}
}
```

Somebody told me, there must also be something like a identification number for the document. But I cant find anything about it. The number here is used for the "Revision". Is it correct with this attribute?

Here is the link to the document

[HTML5 Specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html)

Comment: I know this has been answered, but I thought I should point out that a nifty tool that generates this type of output can be found at [this page](http://w2.syronex.com/jmr/w3c-biblio). I am in no way affiliated with it, it just seems too useful not to pass along.

Comment: @Cronco: You should put that link in an answer. It's way too useful to be hidden in comments.

Comment: @TomasLycken It was initially an answer, and the first comment on it said "This is a rather a comment than an answer". 

Now I'm confused. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a sample bibtex entry for a w3c page:

```
@TechReport{Maler:04:EML,
  author      = "Eve Maler and Jean Paoli and C. M. Sperberg-McQueen and Fran\c{c}ois Yergeau and Tim Bray",
  title       = "Extensible Markup Language ({XML}) 1.0 (Third Edition)",
  month       = feb,
  note        = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204",
  year        = "2004",
  type        = "first Edition of a Recommendation",
  institution = "W3C",
}
```

The identification number for this page the 20040204, which you can see in the "note". The page link that you have given is currently under construction. Alternatively, you can select one of the versions and cite that.

Comment: thank you, so if I only want to mention the 20040204, I´d put it in the note-tag?

Comment: yup.. that's right!

Answer (score 7):

[This website](http://w2.syronex.com/jmr/w3c-biblio) generates BibTeX references for W3C documents. For example, given the URL

> https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/

it currently produces:

```
@TechReport{Eden:18:H,
  author      = "Terence Eden and Xiaoqian Wu and Sangwhan Moon and Shwetank Dixit and Scott O'Hara and Patricia Aas and Bruce Lawson",
  title       = "{HTML} 5.3",
  month       = aug,
  note        = "https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-html53-20180809/",
  year        = "2018",
  bibsource   = "http://w2.syronex.com/jmr/w3c-biblio",
  type        = "{W3C} Working Draft",
  institution = "W3C",
}
```

Note that it automatically resolves the URL (which points to the latest version) to the current version (20180809), so if you repeat this in the future you might get a different result. Also, this only works for documents published on www.w3.org; the dev.w3.org link in your question now redirects to w3c.github.io, which isn’t directly supported (you have to use the “latest published version” link from that document).

Comment: One problem with that nice tool is that it seems to destroy the order of authors. For instance, it returns   `author      = "Markus Lanthaler and David Wood and Richard Cyganiak"` for https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf11-concepts-20140225/, while it should be Cyganiak, Wood, Lanthaler.